# API for Microsoft OneNote 2010 + SkyDrive Web Services?

Tags: onenote, onedrive

I am quite familiar with the Microsoft OneNote 2007 and 2010 APIs, however these interface directly with OneNote itself. In 2010 we have the great facility of syncing OneNote with SkyDrive. This works really well. We can also use the OneNote Web App, Windows Phone 7 and now the iPhone app to access our documents.

My question is this, is there any way of accessing the SkyDrive (or similiar) API directly to enable access to our OneNote notebooks on SkyDrive itself? I trust existing OneNote Uers will see the power of this.

Opening up fiddler I see all sorts of calls to http://docs.live.net/SkyDocsService.svc. The services are also referenced in a forum post by Daniel "Mr OneNote" Escapa on a forum post below:

> OneNote has a 3 screen solution with the 2010 release.  We will have the desktop app, the web app and a mobile app all which sync to the same place in the cloud to Windows Live.  This will allow you to do all of the same things you mention above.  So when you are at your parents you can use the browser to view your notes (IE, Firefox & Safari).  You can also view your notes in the Android browser on your phone and finally I hope there is a OneNote app for the Android in the future.  For example there is a 3rd party group which has released an iPhone solution for OneNote 2007 even without all of these web services we are adding in Office 2010.
>
> [Daniel Escapa](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/office2010/thread/6d739e7a-fdf7-415e-8c85-ca0c8a8f5e3a/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We finally have a result! Read [Scott Hanselman](http://twitter.com/shanselman)'s blog post, [OneNote and Microsoft's quiet API revolution](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OneNoteAndMicrosoftsQuietAPIRevolution.aspx) of 17 March 2014 which breaks the news on the new [OneNote REST API](http://dev.onenote.com/).

Answer (score 1):

This is supported REST SKYDRIVE API http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826521.aspx

Video:The complete developer's guide to the SkyDrive API: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/PLAT-134C

SkyDrive core concepts: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826545.aspx

Create, read, update, and delete folders and files, and get links to files so that other users can access those files directly.: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826531.aspx

Create, read, update, and delete albums, photos, videos, and audio. Read, create, and delete tags on photos and videos.: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826522.aspx

Code Samples (Interactive SDK): http://isdk.dev.live.com/ISDK.aspx

Comment: Thank you, from this and my previous research it doesn't seem to offer any API access to OneNote though, right?

Comment: One note can be access via COM similiar to word. Im not sure of the specifics of your solution, but you could create / edit one-note documents via COM on the server with one note installed and upload / download edit files via skydrive api.

Comment: One note COM references:   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff796230.aspx     http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj680118.aspx